# Does Gluon Mobile/GraalVM supporting the modul javafx.media on Android and IOS?

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile, graalvm-native-image

I learned that javafx.media does not work in a native image on Windows yet. It should work on Linux.  But I can't find informations about Android and IOS. Does anyone know on which platforms the media modul works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaFX media works on Linux,For Android and iOS you can use Gluon Attach, that provides the VideoService and the AudioService to leverage native media frameworks, see https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/javadoc/4.0.11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As José wrote: For Android and iOS you can use Gluon Attach, that provides the VideoService and the AudioService to leverage native media frameworks.